# Android Smooth Multi-touch Drawing

Tags: java, android, drawing, multi-touch

I'm trying make a simple Drawing app. I'd like smooth finger drawing simple curves. And use multi-touch. I've following code:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Path path : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float xPos = event.getX();
    float yPos = event.getY();

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        path.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
                    paths.add(path);
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        path.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
                    paths.add(path);
    }

    invalidate();

    return true;
}
```

Is where any other way? How can I draw by three fingers and nicely smooth?

Comment: So what happens with the code you have now? Also you need to remember that there is many different devices and not all handle multi-touch equally well.

Comment: @Warpzit it's drawing what i draw by finger but it's so slow. I think it's because of adding too much paths to array list. But if I clear it. It'll delete my previous curves. Should I convert them to anything?
I'd like to use this app for my needs. My phone support multi-touch so I'd like to use it.

Comment: Don't think its because of something, you need to test it. Try adding logcat that prints out the lenght of the path. And don't run it in debug mode as that will make it run slow by default :)

Comment: After a while is the size of array above 100 and it's slower and slower. I tried add paths.clear(); into onDrow event. And it's fast now. But there is a problem what I write above.
Can I draw in touchEvent, without using variables? Just call draw?

Answer (score 1):

The `MotionEvent` has historical information embedded in it for this type of application. There is a nice example at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html under the Batching heading

Comment: Thanks, it works perfects!
Here is nice example of use for any other who had the same problem:
http://corner.squareup.com/2010/07/smooth-signatures.html

For multitouch I used event.getPointerCount(); and then event.getX(pointer_index);

Comment: Hi, how did you did this with multitouch? Need to "save" the points to draw? I really apreciate if you can post this part of code

Answer (score 1):

Here example for copy-paste. Just create class that extend View and implement following methods.

```
private final Paint paint = new Paint(); // Don't forgot to init color, form etc.

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int size = paths.size(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Path path = paths.get(i);
        if (path != null) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
    }
}

private HashMap<Integer, Float> mX = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
private HashMap<Integer, Float> mY = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
private HashMap<Integer, Path> paths = new HashMap<Integer, Path>();

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

    Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent");

    switch (maskedAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            for (int size = event.getPointerCount(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Path p = new Path();
                p.moveTo(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
                paths.put(event.getPointerId(i), p);
                mX.put(event.getPointerId(i), event.getX(i));
                mY.put(event.getPointerId(i), event.getY(i));
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            for (int size = event.getPointerCount(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Path p = paths.get(event.getPointerId(i));
                if (p != null) {
                    float x = event.getX(i);
                    float y = event.getY(i);
                    p.quadTo(mX.get(event.getPointerId(i)), mY.get(event.getPointerId(i)), (x + mX.get(event.getPointerId(i))) / 2,
                            (y + mY.get(event.getPointerId(i))) / 2);
                    mX.put(event.getPointerId(i), event.getX(i));
                    mY.put(event.getPointerId(i), event.getY(i));
                }
            }
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            for (int size = event.getPointerCount(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Path p = paths.get(event.getPointerId(i));
                if (p != null) {
                    p.lineTo(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
                    invalidate();
                    paths.remove(event.getPointerId(i));
                    mX.remove(event.getPointerId(i));
                    mY.remove(event.getPointerId(i));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```